# Simplifying the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, stochastic-processes

$$sp \sum_{k=1}^\infty(s(1-p))^{k-1} = \frac{sp}{1-s(1-p)}$$

I am struggling with these series. I've learned a lot about them (E.g. Maclaurin series for e^x was used in one problem). However, for this one I simply don't know how to derive it.

Further, do you recommend any methods to solving these on my own? I saw how the series for e^x was derived and it seemed quite doable though a bit more creative than I believe myself to be :(

Thank you in advance!

P.S. This is for Stochastic Processes. I'm working on a problem for finding the mean and variance using the Probability Generating Function.

Comment: This is just a geometric series!

Comment: $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}$ if $|x| < 1$.